# Is it possible to use Require.js in Onsen UI framework?

Tags: requirejs, onsen-ui

I like to use require.js cordova app in Onsen UI framework. but before i need to know is it possible to use require.js in onsen ?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem to use require.js in an Onsen UI project. Onsen UI is just a library after all.

Just note that Onsen UI includes not only javascript, but also css styles, which you will need to add in order for it to work.

If all else fails you can also just load Onsen UI via a script tag and then use require.js for the rest of the project.

Anyway it should be possible - if you run into any trouble feel free to make a question about the specific problem at hand. :)

Answer (score 0):

As of july 2018, it does not work due to a bug in Onsen UI: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/2360